# Read key text from text file until next line break

Tags: vba, excel

I have a text file like so:

```
----------------DELEGATE TIME & RESOURCE STATS-----------------
A Type: Supplier Registration
A Component: Bid preparation (K/O, overview doc, review, decision)
A Completed By: Mark O'Brien
A Hours: 1
-------------------------END OF STATS--------------------------
```

Then my Excel VBA code scans my notepad file and gets the values following the colons:

```
A Type: {Get Value}
A Component: {Get Value}
A Completed By: {Get Value}
A Hours: {Get Value}
```

My Code:

```
Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer
myFile = "\\MI-FILESERVE1\Shared Folders\Shared_Business_Dev\Tenders\" & Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " - " & M & " - " & Y & "\log.txt"

Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
     text = text & textline
Loop
Close #1


A = InStr(text, "A Type")
1= Mid(text, A + 8, 50)
```

using this section of code gives me the following 'Supplier Registration' value by looking for the word 'A Type' and then trimming the 'A Type' from the value.

The problem with using this line:

```
1= Mid(text, A + 8, 50)
```

is I am having to define how many characters long the value is going to be, where in actual fact each value will be a different length of characters every time so instead of using number of characters can I do something like get the complete length of characters after 'A Type: ' until the next line break so that I am then not also getting:

```
Supplier RegistrationA Component:......
```

Please can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: @Markharris please see [What to do when someone answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and upvote/mark as accepted the answer that is the best solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways. The quickest one could be `Split`:

```
dim result as variant
Line Input #1, textline
result = Split(texteline, ": ")
debug.print result(0) & ": " & result(1)
```

Comment: This is an easy yet practicable solution! Depending on your values, you might want to use something more complex as separator to avoid splitting too often if you separator can appear in your values.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be with `Mid`:

```
Mid(Text, InStr(Text, ":") + 2, Len(Text))
```

The `InStr` finds the starting position, the `+ 2` makes it start at the first Character and `Len(Text)` sets the lenght of the `String`.

**Update:**

With your specific code it would look like this:

```
Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer
myFile = "\\MI-FILESERVE1\Shared Folders\Shared_Business_Dev\Tenders\" & Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " - " & M & " - " & Y & "\log.txt"


Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    If Left(textline, 1) <> "-" Then
        text = Mid(textline, InStr(textline, ":") + 2, Len(textline))
        'proces text code here
    End If
Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare more variable and replace do until loop using the code below

```
' Declare necessary variable
Dim aType As String
Dim aComponent As String
Dim aCompleted As String
Dim aHours As String
Dim i As Long


' Replace this do loop to your do loop code
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    i = InStr(textline, "A Type:")
    If InStr(textline, "A Type:") > 0 Then
        aType = Mid(textline, A + 8, Len(textline))
    End If

    i = InStr(textline, "A Component:")
    If InStr(textline, "A Component:") > 0 Then
        aType = Mid(textline, A + 13, Len(textline))
    End If

    i = InStr(textline, "A Completed By:")
    If InStr(textline, "A Completed By:") > 0 Then
        aType = Mid(textline, A + 16, Len(textline))
    End If

    i = InStr(textline, "A Hours:")
    If InStr(textline, "A Hours:") > 0 Then
        aType = Mid(textline, A + 9, Len(textline))
    End If
Loop
```